# Unit conversion in cosmology

Tags: cosmology, units

In cosmology (Dodelson) , the natural unit is $\hbar=1, c=1, k_B=1 $. There the author writes the critical density of the universe $\rho_{cr}$ as
\begin{align*}
\rho_{cr}&=1.879 \ h^2\ \times 10^{-29}\ \text{gm/cm$^3$} \\
         &= 8.098 \ h^2 \ \times 10^{-11}\ \text{eV$^4$}
\end{align*}
It is the conversion of units that I am not able to understand.

Comment: The section “Natural units (particle physics and cosmology)” at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units shows how mass and length (and therefore mass density) can be measured in eV when $\hbar$ and $c$ are 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just do the following:
$$
\rho_{cr} = 1.879\cdot 10^{-26}\frac{\text{kg}}{\text{m}^{3}} = 1.879\cdot 10^{-26}(\text{kg}\cdot c^{2})\frac{(\hbar c)^{3}}{\text{m}^{3}}\frac{1}{c^{2}(\hbar c)^{3}}
$$
Taking into account that 
$$
\text{kg}\cdot c^{2} = 9\cdot 10^{16}\text{ J} \approx 5.6 \cdot 10^{35}\text{ eV},
$$
$$
\frac{(\hbar c)^{3}}{\text{m}^{3}}\approx 7.7\cdot 10^{-21}\text{ eV}^{3},
$$

you obtain an expression for $\rho_{cr}$ in terms of $\hbar, c$:
$$
\rho_{cr} \approx 8.1\cdot 10^{-11}\text{ eV}^{4}\frac{1}{c^{2}(\hbar c)^{3}}
$$
In natural units, $c = \hbar = 1$, which gives you the result.